# SQL Server uses wrong execution plan when using dynamic order by clause with when

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-execution-plan

We have a stored procedure with query like this in it:

```
   SELECT    
       MyTable.Id, MyTable.Date_Start, 
       MySeccondTable.Name + ' ' + MySeccondTable.Family AS OwnerName
   FROM 
       MyTable 
   INNER JOIN 
       MySeccondTable ON MyTable.UserId = MySeccondTable.Id 
   WHERE
       (@Date_StartMin IS NULL OR MyTable.Date_Start >= @Date_StartMin)         
   ORDER BY
       CASE 
          WHEN (@SortOrder = 'Id') AND (@ASC = 1)   
             THEN MyTable.Id
       END ASC,             
       CASE 
          WHEN (@SortOrder = 'Id') AND (@ASC = 0)  
             THEN MyTable.Id
       END DESC
```

that the `@Date_StartMin` and `@SortOrder` are parameters sending by the user to stored procedure.

This query works correctly. But when we check the execution plan we saw SQL Server uses an inefficient execution plan that takes out 3 times more to execute

When we change query to this :

```
SELECT    
    MyTable.Id, MyTable.Date_Start, 
    MySeccondTable.Name + ' ' + MySeccondTable.Family AS OwnerName
FROM 
    MyTable 
INNER JOIN 
    MySeccondTable ON MyTable.UserId = MySeccondTable.Id 
WHERE
    (@Date_StartMin IS NULL OR MyTable.Date_Start >= @Date_StartMin)            
ORDER BY
    CASE 
       WHEN (2 > 1) AND (@ASC = 1)  
          THEN MyTable.Id                   
    END ASC ,               
    CASE 
       WHEN (2 > 1) AND (@ASC = 0)  
          THEN MyTable.Id                   
    END DESC
```

everything takes place and the execution time fixed.

So what's the point?
how can we fix this issue?

Comment: Google for "parameter sniffing", take a look at "OPTIMIZE FOR/RECOMPILE" options. And I'd suggest to think of moving sorting to the client-side. There is one more point of possible troubles with the plan - OR inside WHERE predicate. That's about RECOMPILE option too.

Comment: we used `WITH RECOMPILE` but no change effected

Comment: post execution plan

Comment: What version of SQL server?

Comment: MS SQL SERVER 2016

Answer (score 0):

Even if the query looks like it is using the right execution plan, it may not for all combinations of the variables.  The problem is that SQL Server caches execution plans, the cached plan is usually based on the first run of the stored procedure.  This process is called "parameter sniffing".

You may be able to get around this using the with recompile option:

```
SELECT t1.Id, t2.Date_Start, 
       t2.Name + ' ' + t2.Family AS OwnerName
 FROM MyTable t INNER JOIN 
      MySeccondTable t2
      ON t.UserId = t2.Id 
 WHERE (@Date_StartMin IS NULL OR t.Date_Start >= @Date_StartMin)         
 ORDER BY (CASE WHEN (@SortOrder = 'Id') AND (@ASC = 1) THEN t.Id
           END) ASC,             
          (CASE WHEN (@SortOrder = 'Id') AND (@ASC = 0)  
                THEN t.Id
           END) DESC
 OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

However, I'm not 100% sure about how parameter sniffing, recompile, and compiler optimizations on constants in the `ORDER BY` work together.

I would probably use dynamic SQL:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
set @sql = '
    SELECT t1.Id, t2.Date_Start, t2.Name + ' ' + t2.Family AS OwnerName
     FROM MyTable t INNER JOIN 
          MySeccondTable t2
          ON t.UserId = t2.Id 
     WHERE (@Date_StartMin IS NULL OR t.Date_Start >= @Date_StartMin)         
     ORDER BY @SortOrder @Asc
     OPTION (RECOMPILE)';
set @sql = REPLACE(REPLACE(@sql, '@SortOrder', COALESCE(@SortOrder, '')
                          ), '@Asc', COALESCE(@Asc, '')
                  );

exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@Date_StartMin Date', @Date_StartMin = @Date_StartMin;
```